# How to load an onnx model using ONNX.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, onnx

I am trying to import an ONNX model using onnxjs, but I get the below error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot resolve operator 'Cast' with opsets: ai.onnx v11
```

Below shows a code snippet from my html file.

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Load ONNX.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxjs/dist/onnx.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Code that consume ONNX.js -->
    <script>
        async function test(){
            const sess = new onnx.InferenceSession()
            await sess.loadModel('./onnx_model.onnx')
            }
        test()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will load [Resnet 50 model](https://microsoft.github.io/onnxjs-demo/#/resnet50)

```js
const sess = new onnx.InferenceSession()
async function test(){
  console.time("loading model")
  await sess.loadModel('https://microsoft.github.io/onnxjs-demo/resnet50v2.onnx')
  console.timeEnd("loading model")

  console.log("model loaded");
}
document.querySelector('#load').addEventListener('click', test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxjs/dist/onnx.min.js"></script>

<button id="load">load model</button>
```

The message suggest something to do with the
[Cast operator](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md)
not being supported by opset 11, maybe you want to use [Cast-9](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Changelog.md#Cast-9). Maybe you have to generate a new model.

### Edit

Your model loads using onnxruntime python

```py
sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('../../Downloads/onnx_model.onnx');
{i.name: i.shape for i in sess.get_inputs()}
{o.name: o.shape for o in sess.get_outputs()}
```

```txt
{'input_ids': ['batch', 'sequence'],
 'attention_mask': ['batch', 'sequence'],
 'token_type_ids': ['batch', 'sequence']}

{'output_0': ['batch', 2]}
```

#### An Idea

You will probably have to debug it your self, hopefully the only problem is the cast operator.

You start looking [here](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxjs/blob/master/docs/operators.md) the operator support for onnxjs, and rewrite parts of the model where the operator appears.

For instance, the Cast operator appears only once, you can locate it as follows

```py
import onnx
model = onnx.load('../../Downloads/onnx_model.onnx')
for node in model.graph.node:
    if 'cast' in node.op_type.lower():
        print(node.name, node.op_type)
```

That will print

```
Cast_2 Cast
```

Using https://netron.app/ (Or the desktop version) you can see that it is
[image: netron-view]

So you should simply rewrite how your attention mask is processed in the model, a possible solution would be to let `unsqueeze` and `cast` operations outside the model.

Comment: May i know is there a way to change my opset version from 11 to 9?

Comment: The opset can be specified when exporting your model

Comment: Thank you Bob, I have changed the version to 9 but it does not work and prompt the following error:
Unsupported: ONNX export of Slice with dynamic inputs. DynamicSlice is a deprecated experimental op. Please use statically allocated variables or export to a higher opset version.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer. If you share your model so that it can inspect maybe we can find a way to load it correctly. If you want more specific help you will have to share your model generation script. If you can't disclose the model you may consider exporting it before training, or depending on how the characteristics of the project you may want a consultancy under an NDA.

Comment: Here is the link to my onnxModel, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HWBIGI4XN1hSbJN88cNYxR1Su2mJQSJu?usp=sharing
Thanks for your help bob

Comment: I can load the model in python

Comment: Ya, I can load it in python as well but I wanted to load it in onnxjs/tensorflowjs, which is used later in a chrome extension. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling on this, onnxjs describes which tensor operations it's able to use for each exported onnx file here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxjs/blob/master/docs/operators.md

As of 2023, that list shows that the `Cast` operation is only supported for .onnx opset versions `6-8` and `9+` (9 onward). `Cast` is currently supported in opset 11, so presumably when OP posted this a year ago support for v11 was still in development. If a version that *should* work doesn't, like when OP tried v9 and it still didn't work, I would recommend trying other listed versions, like 8, 7, 10, or 6. Onnxjs is no longer being developed so the docs may occasionally be inaccurate.

You set the opset version when exporting a .onnx file. For example in PyTorch, the onnx export function is [`torch.onnx.export()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#torch.onnx.export). This could look like:

> !pip install onnx
> torch_model = (...load a torch model...)
>
> torch_model.to('cpu')
> dummy_input = torch.zeros(1, 1, 28, 28).to('cpu')
> torch_model.eval()
>
> torch.onnx.export(torch_model, dummy_input, 'model_exported.onnx', verbose=True, opset_version=8)

(Leaving this here for anyone who was confused on this like I was)